# webRTC and peer.js connection balck screen even after passing ids and making and answering a call form peer js

Tags: webrtc

**Peer.js and webRtc balck screen problem on different network**

I am using socket.io with peer.js as webRTC library. When two devices are connected to same room, passed the peer id, one device making peer call and another device answering call . Both on them sharing their video stream. To double check, the screen also shows its own video from stream. Cameras are permitted and can see own video. But when shared, can't see other's video, it becomes black screen.

After initial id sharing with socket.io, one device makes peer call , another device gets the call and also answer it. so Peer connection is getting through, right ? but the video on other's device is black screen. If peer call and answer is getting through, then why not the video?

video source, stream and other function have no fault as I checked multiple times. on same network between multiple devices it works perfectly. But doesn't work on devices on different network.